# Date time between not working in typescript with typeorm in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I want to retrieve data between given date time range.
When I try to retrieve data from DBeaver tool, it'll return all the data.
here is my query tried

```
SELECT id, "vehicleNo", "vehicleClass",  "issuedOn", "modifiedOn", "paidOn","ticketStatusId"
FROM public.ticket where "paidOn" >= '2019-04-16 02:30:00 AM' and "paidOn" <= '2019-04-16 11:30:00 AM';
```

But when I use typeorm then,it will not return all the data
here is my typeorm code

```
const records = await getConnection().getRepository(Ticket)
                .createQueryBuilder("ticket")
                .innerJoinAndSelect("ticket.ticketStatus", "ticketStatus")
                .where(`ticket.paidOn >= :startDate AND ticket.paidOn <= :endDate
                AND ticket.modifiedBy = :email AND ticketStatus.title = :status `,
                    { startDate: fromDate, endDate: toDate, email: uemail, status: "Paid"})
                .orderBy("ticket.paidOn", "DESC")
                .getMany();
```

here is the correct dataset has to return. (8 records)
[image]

but it's returning 4 records only
[image]

Comment: Looks like a timezone problem, what TZ do you use in your node app? Because the timestamp used by TypeOrm will be in node's TZ, and your raw query in your SQL tool is in database's TZ. I bet they are not the same.

Comment: @zenbeni,thanks alot for your reply,sorry I didn't get what did you mean by TZ use in node app,I used timestamptz for the"issiedOn" column data type

Comment: The default TZ of node if the one defined in the OS, you can define it when you run node with an environment variable named "TZ", for instance TZ=UTC. The timezone in postgresql is defined in the conf file.

Comment: sorry,I can't understand what your are saying.Please explain which place to ad TZ=UTC

Comment: visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59452233/typeorm-how-to-search-for-a-range-of-date-in-postgressql/73645706#73645706

Answer (score 8):

```
import { startOfDay, endOfDay } from 'date-fns';
import { Between, Equal } from "typeorm";
//...
let findArgs = { 
  where:{
    date: Between(startOfDay(webInputArgs.date).toISOString(), endOfDay(webInputArgs.date).toISOString()), 
    userId: Equal(ctx.req.session.userId)
  }
};
return entity.find(findArgs) as any;
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the library: https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started

After one example:

- BeforeDate
- AfterDate
- BetweenDates

```
// BeforeDate
const BeforeDate = (date: Date) => Between(subYears(date, 100), date);
return await this.connection.getRepository(ExampleEntity)
      .find({ createdAt: BeforeDate(new Date()) });

// AfterDate
const AfterDate = (date: Date) => Between(date, addYears(date, 100));
    return await this.connection.getRepository(ExampleEntity)
      .find({ createdAt: BeforeDate(new Date()) });

// BetweenDates
// TypeORM Query Operators with validation before 2 months and actual date plus one day
    const BetweenDates = (date: Date) => Between(subMonths(date, 2), addDays(date, 1));

    return await this.connection.getRepository(ExampleEntity)
      .find({
        where: {
          createdAt: BetweenDates(new Date()),
        },
      });
```

Comment: This is making three request to the database, this could be achieved with a single query?