# TypeORM : How to search for a range of Date in PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, date, typeorm, iso8601

consider an [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date 
and want to do a query using Typeorm and PostgreSQL

```
 if (orderInput.begining && orderInput.ending)
     query.andWhere(`order.createdAt
     BETWEEN to_timestamp(${orderInput.begining} / 1000 )
     AND to_timestamp(${orderInput.ending} / 1000 );
`);
```

These are my argument:
`"2010-12-24T21:32:33.477Z"`
`"2019-12-24T21:32:33.477Z"`
and this is the underhood query and the err :

```
query failed: SELECT DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."order_id" as "ids_order_id" FROM (SELECT "order"."id" AS "order_id", "order"."createdAt" AS "order_createdAt"
 FROM "order" "order" INNER JOIN "ware" "ware" ON "ware"."id"="order"."wareId" WHERE "order"."organizationId" = $1 AND "order"."createdAt"
                 BETWEEN Wed Dec 25 2019 01:02:33 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time) 
                 AND Wed Dec 25 2019 01:02:33 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time) ;) "distinctAlias" ORDER BY "order_id" ASC LIMIT 25 -- PARAMETERS: ["8fd87ced-eb58-4460-b74e-d5a2b1491622"]
error: { error: syntax error at or near "Dec"
```

I guess it's because of that the arguments are not taken wraped in ' ' (qoutes) 
 I don't know how to pass the arguments to typescript as standard `ISO8606 Date`(typescript) with ' '(qoutes) to be then passed to PostgreSQL

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what's the problem?  Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: @richyen I added the err, thanks in advance

Comment: try using quotes  'Wed Dec 25 2019 01:02:33 GMT+0330'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Typescript And PostgreSQL know ISO8601 well and there is no need to to_timestamp() for PostgreSQL.
So this works like a chram:

```
if (orderInput.begining && orderInput.ending)
    query.andWhere(
       `"order"."createdAt"
    BETWEEN :begin
       AND :end`
    ,{ begin: orderInput.begining, end: orderInput.ending);
```

NOTE: in JavaScript, you can easily make a ISO8601 standard Date in this way:

```
const date = new Date(2020,2,2)
const iso  = date.toISOString()
```

Comment: Did you mean ISO 8601 ? (I'm not sure ISO8606 is relevant for date standards)

Comment: @AmitPaz Yep, you're right.

Answer (score 5):

My solution as of now(2021-05-26) using Between of TypeORM ([docs](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options)):

```
const orders = await this.orderRepo.find({
  where: {
    createdAt: Between(
      new Date(orderInput.begining).toISOString(),
      new Date(orderInput.ending)).toISOString(),
    ),
  },
  skip: skip || 0,
  take: take || 10,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
await this.YOUR_REPOSITORY
       .createQueryBuilder("order")
       .where('order.createdAt BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate', { startDate: orderInput.begining, endDate: orderInput.ending })
       .getMany();
```